# how to insert variable into sql row

Tags: c++, sql

I am writing a code that counts the sorting time of different arrays and must write the result to the database. Three tables, name , time and array size. There are no problems with the names, but when I need to write to the database a number that is stored in an int variable, I have problems. (it just writes as text)
I will attach part of the code with one sort, the rest is the same, it makes no sense to show them additionally.
there is a function that makes sql query. How can I pass the contents of a variable into it?

```
int main(){
    DataBase *base= new DataBase();
    openBd("test1Den\0");
        int step = 100;
        bool flag1 = 1 , flag2 = 1, flag3 = 1 , flag4 = 1, flag5 = 1 , flag6 = 1;
        cout << "  bubbleSort  "<<"  selectionSort  "<<"  countsort  "<< "  quickSort  "<<"  insertionSort  "<< "  mergeSort"<<endl;
            std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> start;
            std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> end;
            chrono::duration<double> diff;
        for(int arsize = 100; arsize <= 1000; arsize += step){
            int* ar = new int[arsize];
            cout<< arsize <<"\t";
            randomFilling(ar , arsize ,0 , 999);

            if ( flag1 ){
                    start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
                    bubbleSort(ar,arsize);
                    end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
                    diff = end - start;
            request_insert_create("INSERT INTO Sorts(nameSort) VALUES('bubblesort');");
            request_insert_create("INSERT INTO SizeArs(sizeAr) VALUES(arsize);");
                    cout<< diff.count()<< "\t";
    
                    if( diff.count() > 50){

                            flag1 = false;

                    }
            }
            else {
                    cout << "-----" << "\t";
            }
```

in this case arsize is an int variable, I need to write it to the database.
Error example:
INSERT INTO SizeArs(sizeAr) VALUES(arsize); : no such column: arsize

Comment: _`VALUES(arsize)`_ `arsize` is part of the SQL literal text here. You'll need to use a parameterized query to insert values from your c++ variables there.

Comment: ... and please don't try to change the char array passed to `request_insert_create()` directly. You're supposed to use `VALUES(?)` and pass those `?` as separate parameters.

Comment: Can you elaborate on requests? Maybe some link to an explanation of their work or just an example of a solution to my case

Comment: You don't even told which database framework you're working with, so how could I? Read the documentation of your framework.

Answer (score 0):

*`arsize`* inside your SQL statement  `"INSERT INTO SizeArs(sizeAr) VALUES(arsize);"` isn't accessible, when the DB Server executes that statement, hence the error.
The value needs to be bound in a way.

A very simple and naive solution for your immediate problem, and "binding" the variable could be:

```
std::string insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO SizeArs(sizeAr) VALUES("s + std::to_string(arsize) + ");"
request_insert_create(insert_stmt.c_str());
```

But as I mentioned in my comments, that's not a recommended way to use SQL value bindings.
Regarding standard SQL I think there are standards for parameterized queries.
That's the way to go.